# Distributing Different Items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft

Currently, my set-up uses a chest with several advanced wooden transport pipes, each keyed to a single item. Is there anyway to have one pipe pull from the chest and then somehow distribute several different items to different chests/automatic crafting tables?

Comment: logistic pipes will be your answer

Comment: @ratchetfreak Buildcraft is included in Tekkit, as well as the Technic-pack.

Comment: @JeffreyLin but the question is pure buildcraft, it is also included in the FTB pack

Answer (score 4):

I think Diamond pipes are what you're looking for. They allow you to sort the incoming items in any of the 6 possible exits, via a filter opened by right-clicking.